# Can openssh ignore login notifications by specific IP address?

Tags: ssh, debian, openssh, notifications

I'm use pushover on my openssh server to notifications, but I want to ignore my own ip address, to not send a notification when I connect to the server.

I have a dynamic ip address, so I wrote a small script to get my current ip from home to the server, so the current ip is in a text file, 
can ssh server read this address from the file and ignore notifications for this address?